# Navicat ignores MAMP PRO

Tags: macos, mamp

I'm using Navicat Premium 10.1.1 and MAMP PRO 2.1.4.

MAMP PRO is set to use the port 3306 for MySQL. When I try to create a new MySQL connection in Navicat, I set the hostname as localhost, port as 3306, username and password as root. 
But, when testing connection, it shows "`Can't connect to MySQL server on '127.0.0.1' (61)`".

Does someone know what can be the problem?

Notes:

1. MAMP PRO is already started;
2. I also tried to use 127.0.0.1 instead of localhost as the hostname.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Uncheck "Allow local access only" in Server > MySQL.

Comment: Very odd they set this as the default.

Answer (score 1):

OK. I just got it.

I had to change in the `Connection properties` of the connection I created, the following:

In the `Advanced` tab:

1. Check the `Use socket file` option
2. Set this path for the field above:
   `/Applications/MAMP/tmp/mysql/mysql.sock`

Note that the path to use is available in `/Applications/MAMP/bin/startMysql.sh` (given that I'm using MySQL).

Answer (score 1):

Allowing local access resolved it for me.

Comment: Can you add a bit more detail to improve this answer?